# How can i ignore error to continue project in c# code?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, error-handling

I am working on a windows form application. when i run the project in one of my class error occurs. (see below image)

[image]

But when i press continue button The project runs well. Also, I can not  delete this line of code. How can I ignore this error to continue project?

Comment: Dont ignore it.  Fix it.  In the old days that error could result in the BSOD

Comment: Generally you shouldn't ignore errors, they're an error for a reason. Something is broken, fix it. If you want to handle it or even ignore it then look at `try/catch' blocks.

Comment: I tried so hard to fix this error but did not. That's why I'm going to ignore

Comment: If you can absolutely guarantee that the rest of the program will run fine without this part of the code working successfully then go for it. It's still a terrible idea.

Comment: @hamid - You fail to realize the severity of this error.  An unbalanced stack means your application is in an unstable state, and can cause all kinds of random problems further down the road.  If you ignore this problem now, you will have problems later, and not be able to trace it back to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use try-catch:

```
try {
    // code here
} catch (Exception) {
    // do something or nothing if caught
}
```

Or, if you want to catch a specified exception, do this:

```
try {
    // code here
} catch (/* exception class here */) {
    // do something or nothing if caught
}
```

For instance, if you want to catch NullReferenceException, then do this:

```
try {
    // code here
} catch (NullReferenceException) {
    // do something or nothing if caught
}
```

If you want to use exception data, define exception as a variable, like this:

```
try {
    // code here
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something or nothing if caught
}
```

In Visual Studio, you can insert a try-catch snippet by typing `try` and double-hitting Tab key.

There's also try-catch-finally. Example:

```
try {
    // code here
} catch (Exception) {
    // do something or nothing if caught
} finally {
    // perform some cleanup here
}
```

In Visual Studio, you can type `tryf` and double-hit Tab key to insert a try-catch-finally snippet.

You can also just perform some cleanup using try-finally without getting any error:

```
try {
    // code here
} finally {
    // perform some cleanup here
}
```

More info on MSDN about [try-catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx), [try-finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx) and [try-catch-finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989.aspx).

But still, if an error occurs, that mean something is wrong. Google some information about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using trycatch :

```
try{
//your code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
//Log the exception 'ex'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `TryCatch` handling:

```
// some code

try
{
    // "try" some code here 
    // You may put the line that may cause an error here

} catch(Exception ex)
{
    // This part will get executed if above did not work (error - threw an exception)
    // You may just keep it empty -> error will be ignored
    // or log `ex` information
    // or do something anything else
}

// control will continue - no crash
// some other code
```

For more information, Read [C# - Exception Handling](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_exception_handling.htm).